# Getting error Error: Could not find or load main class JavaFixHistoryMiner, Don't know how to fix

Tags: java

Everything in the code seems fine. I do not understand why it is giving me this error.

Using Eclipse IDE (Juno), I've clicked "Run" and got the following message on the console:

> Error: Could not find or load main class JavaFixHistoryMiner

This was an imported file, I also added an external library

```
/**
 * Example of how to request and process historical rate data from the Java API 
 * 
 * @author rkichenama
 */
public class JavaFixHistoryMiner
implements IGenericMessageListener, IStatusMessageListener
{
    private static final String server = "http://www.fxcorporate.com/Hosts.jsp";
    private static final String TEST_CURRENCY = "EUR/USD";

    private FXCMLoginProperties login;
    private IGateway gateway;
    private String currentRequest;
    private boolean requestComplete;

    private ArrayList<CollateralReport> accounts = new ArrayList<CollateralReport>();
    private HashMap<UTCDate, MarketDataSnapshot> historicalRates = new HashMap<UTCDate, MarketDataSnapshot>();

    private static PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter((OutputStream)System.out, true);
    public PrintWriter getOutput() { return output; }
    public void setOutput(PrintWriter newOutput) { output = newOutput; }

    /**
     * Creates a new JavaFixHistoryMiner with credentials with configuration file
     * 
     * @param username
     * @param password 
     * @param terminal - which terminal to login into, dependent on the type of account, case sensitive
     * @param server - url, like 'http://www.fxcorporate.com/Hosts.jsp'
     * @param file - a local file used to define configuration
     */
    public JavaFixHistoryMiner(String username, String password, String terminal, String file)
    {
        // if file is not specified
        if(file == null)
            // create a local LoginProperty
            this.login = new FXCMLoginProperties(username, password, terminal, server);
        else
            this.login = new FXCMLoginProperties(username, password, terminal, server, file);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new JavaFixHistoryMiner with credentials and no configuration file
     * 
     * @param username
     * @param password
     * @param terminal - which terminal to login into, dependent on the type of account, case sensitive
     * @param server - url, like 'http://www.fxcorporate.com/Hosts.jsp'
     */
    public JavaFixHistoryMiner(String username, String password, String terminal)
    {
        // call the proper constructor
        this(username, password, terminal, null);
    }

    public JavaFixHistoryMiner(String[] args)
    {
        // call the proper constructor
        this(args[0], args[1], args[2], null);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to login with credentials supplied in constructor, assigning self as listeners
     */
    public boolean login()
    {
        return this.login(this, this);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to login with credentials supplied in constructor
     * 
     * @param genericMessageListener - the listener object for trading events
     * @param statusMessageListener - the listener object for status events
     * 
     * @return true if login successful, false if not
     */
    public boolean login(IGenericMessageListener genericMessageListener, IStatusMessageListener statusMessageListener)
    {
        try
        {
            // if the gateway has not been defined
            if(gateway == null)
                // assign it to a new gateway created by the factory
                gateway = GatewayFactory.createGateway();
            // register the generic message listener with the gateway
            gateway.registerGenericMessageListener(genericMessageListener);
            // register the status message listener with the gateway
            gateway.registerStatusMessageListener(statusMessageListener);
            // if the gateway has not been connected
            if(!gateway.isConnected())
            {
                // attempt to login with the local login properties
                gateway.login(this.login);
            }
            else
            {
                // attempt to re-login to the api
                gateway.relogin();
            }
            // set the state of the request to be incomplete
            requestComplete = false;
            // request the current trading session status
            currentRequest = gateway.requestTradingSessionStatus();
            // wait until the request is complete
            while(!requestComplete) {}
            // return that this process was successful
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        // if any error occurred, then return that this process failed
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to logout, assuming that the supplied listeners reference self
     */
    public void logout()
    {
        this.logout(this, this);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to logout, removing the supplied listeners prior to disconnection
     * 
     * @param genericMessageListener - the listener object for trading events
     * @param statusMessageListener - the listener object for status events
     */
    public void logout(IGenericMessageListener genericMessageListener, IStatusMessageListener statusMessageListener)
    {
        // attempt to logout of the api
        gateway.logout();
        // remove the generic message listener, stop listening to updates
        gateway.removeGenericMessageListener(genericMessageListener);
        // remove the status message listener, stop listening to status changes
        gateway.removeStatusMessageListener(statusMessageListener);
    }

    /**
     * Request a refresh of the collateral reports under the current login
     */
    public void retrieveAccounts()
    {
        // if the gateway is null then attempt to login
        if(gateway == null) this.login();
        // set the state of the request to be incomplete
        requestComplete = false;
        // request the refresh of all collateral reports
        currentRequest = gateway.requestAccounts();
        // wait until all the reqports have been processed
        while(!requestComplete) {}
    }

    /**
     * Send a fully formed order to the API and wait for the response.
     *  
     *  @return the market order number of placed trade, NONE if the trade did not execute, null on error 
     */
    public String sendRequest(ITransportable request)
    {
        try
        {
            // set the completion status of the requst to false
            requestComplete = false;
            // send the request message to the api
            currentRequest = gateway.sendMessage(request);
            // wait until the api answers on this particular request
            // while(!requestComplete) {}
            // if there is a value to return, it will be passed by currentResult
            return currentRequest;
        }
        catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        // if an error occured, return no result
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Implementing IStatusMessageListener to capture and process messages sent back from API
     * 
     * @param status - status message received by API
     */
    @Override public void messageArrived(ISessionStatus status)
    {
        // check to the status code
        if(status.getStatusCode() == ISessionStatus.STATUSCODE_ERROR ||
                status.getStatusCode() == ISessionStatus.STATUSCODE_DISCONNECTING ||
                status.getStatusCode() == ISessionStatus.STATUSCODE_CONNECTING ||
                status.getStatusCode() == ISessionStatus.STATUSCODE_CONNECTED ||
                status.getStatusCode() == ISessionStatus.STATUSCODE_CRITICAL_ERROR ||
                status.getStatusCode() == ISessionStatus.STATUSCODE_EXPIRED ||
                status.getStatusCode() == ISessionStatus.STATUSCODE_LOGGINGIN ||
                status.getStatusCode() == ISessionStatus.STATUSCODE_LOGGEDIN ||
                status.getStatusCode() == ISessionStatus.STATUSCODE_PROCESSING ||
                status.getStatusCode() == ISessionStatus.STATUSCODE_DISCONNECTED)
        {
            // display status message
            output.println("\t\t" + status.getStatusMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Implementing IGenericMessageListener to capture and process messages sent back from API
     * 
     * @param message - message received for processing by API
     */
    @Override public void messageArrived(ITransportable message)
    {
        // decide which child function to send an cast instance of the message

        try
        {
            // if it is an instance of CollateralReport, process the collateral report 
            if(message instanceof CollateralReport) messageArrived((CollateralReport)message);
            // if it is an instance of MarketDataSnapshot, process the historical data 
            if(message instanceof MarketDataSnapshot) messageArrived((MarketDataSnapshot)message);
            // if it is an instance of MarketDataRequestReject, process the historical data request error
            if(message instanceof MarketDataRequestReject) messageArrived((MarketDataRequestReject)message);
            // if the message is an instance of TradingSessionStatus, cast it and send to child function
            else if(message instanceof TradingSessionStatus) messageArrived((TradingSessionStatus)message);
        }
        catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(output); }
    }

    /**
     * Separate function to handle collateral report requests
     * 
     * @param cr - message interpreted as an instance of CollateralReport
     */
    public void messageArrived(CollateralReport cr)
    {
        // if this report is the result of a direct request by a waiting process
        if(currentRequest.equals(cr.getRequestID()) && !accounts.contains(cr))
        {
            // add the trading account to the account list
            accounts.add(cr);
            // set the state of the request to be completed only if this is the last collateral report
            // requested
            requestComplete = cr.isLastRptRequested();
        }
    }

    /**

  /**
     * Separate function to handle the trading session status updates and pull the trading instruments
     * 
     * @param tss - the message interpreted as a TradingSessionStatus instance
     */
    public void messageArrived(TradingSessionStatus tss)
    {
        // check to see if there is a request from main application for a session update
        if(currentRequest.equals(tss.getRequestID()))
        {
            // set that the request is complete for any waiting thread
            requestComplete = true;
            // attempt to set up the historical market data request
            try
            {
                // create a new market data request
                MarketDataRequest mdr = new MarketDataRequest();
                // set the subscription type to ask for only a snapshot of the history
                mdr.setSubscriptionRequestType(SubscriptionRequestTypeFactory.SNAPSHOT);
                // request the response to be formated FXCM style
                mdr.setResponseFormat(IFixDefs.MSGTYPE_FXCMRESPONSE);
                // set the intervale of the data candles
                mdr.setFXCMTimingInterval(FXCMTimingIntervalFactory.MIN15);
                // set the type set for the data candles
                mdr.setMDEntryTypeSet(MarketDataRequest.MDENTRYTYPESET_ALL);
                // configure the start and end dates
                Date now = new Date();
                Calendar calendar = (Calendar)Calendar.getInstance().clone();
                calendar.setTime(now);
                calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
                Date beforeNow = calendar.getTime();
                // set the dates and times for the market data request
                mdr.setFXCMStartDate(new UTCDate(beforeNow));
                mdr.setFXCMStartTime(new UTCTimeOnly(beforeNow));
                mdr.setFXCMEndDate(new UTCDate(now));
                mdr.setFXCMEndTime(new UTCTimeOnly(now));
                // set the instrument on which the we want the historical data
                mdr.addRelatedSymbol(tss.getSecurity(TEST_CURRENCY));
                // send the request
                sendRequest(mdr);
            }
            catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Separate function to handle the rejection of a market data historical snapshot
     * 
     * @param mdrr - message interpreted as an instance of MarketDataRequestReject
     */
    public void messageArrived(MarketDataRequestReject mdrr)
    {
        // display note consisting of the reason the request was rejected
        output.println("Historical data rejected; " + mdrr.getMDReqRejReason());
        // set the state of the request to be complete
        requestComplete = true;
    }

    /**
     * Separate function to handle the receipt of market data snapshots
     * 
     * Current dealing rates are retrieved through the same class as historical requests. The difference
     * is that historical requests are 'answers' to a specific request.
     * 
     * @param mds
     */
    public void messageArrived(MarketDataSnapshot mds)
    {
        // if the market data snapshot is part of the answer to a specific request
        try
        {
            if(mds.getRequestID() != null && mds.getRequestID().equals(currentRequest))
            {
                // add that snapshot to the historicalRates table
                synchronized(historicalRates) { historicalRates.put(mds.getDate(), mds); }
                // set the request to be complete only if the continuous flaf is at the end
                requestComplete = (mds.getFXCMContinuousFlag() == IFixDefs.FXCMCONTINUOUS_END);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the historical rates captured
     */
    public void displayHistory()
    {
        // give the table a header
        output.println("Rate 15 minute candle History for " + TEST_CURRENCY);
        // give the table column headings
        output.println("Date\t   Time\t\tOBid\tCBid\tHBid\tLBid");
        // get the keys for the historicalRates table into a sorted list
        SortedSet<UTCDate> candle = new TreeSet<UTCDate>(historicalRates.keySet());
        // define a format for the dates
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
        // make the date formatter above convert from GMT to EST
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
        // go through the keys of the historicalRates table
        for(int i = 0; i < candle.size(); i++)
        {
            // create a single instance of the snapshot
            MarketDataSnapshot candleData;
            synchronized(historicalRates) { candleData = historicalRates.get(candle.toArray()[i]); }
            // convert the key to a Date
            Date candleDate = ((UTCDate)candle.toArray()[i]).toDate();
            // print out the historicalRate table data
            output.println(
                    sdf.format(candleDate) + "\t" +    // the date and time formatted and converted to EST
                            candleData.getBidOpen() + "\t" +   // the open bid for the candle
                            candleData.getBidClose() + "\t" +  // the close bid for the candle
                            candleData.getBidHigh() + "\t" +   // the high bid for the candle
                            candleData.getBidLow());           // the low bid for the candle
        }
        // repeat the table column headings
        output.println("Date\t   Time\t\tOBid\tCBid\tHBid\tLBid");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // create an instance of the JavaFixHistoryMiner
            JavaFixHistoryMiner miner = new JavaFixHistoryMiner("rkichenama", "1311016", "Demo");
            // login to the api
            miner.login();
            // retrieve the trader accounts to ensure login process is complete
            miner.retrieveAccounts();
            // display nore that the history display is delayed
            // partially for theatrics, partially to ensure all the rates are collected
            output.println("Displaying history in");
            // wait ~ 2.5 seconds
            for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--)
            {
                output.println(i + "...");
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            // display the collected rates
            miner.displayHistory();
            // log out of the api
            miner.logout();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your classpath is incorrect, so the JVM can't find your file. It would be helpful in the future if you show your *exact* error message, as well as describe how you are trying to run your program (and if you're trying to run from the command line, show the *exact* command that you're using).

Comment: Thanks for the response, how do I fix my classpath?

Comment: Probably by changing the way you run your program. But as you haven't shown us how you run your program, nobody can say for sure. Edit your question, with the *exact* steps that you take to run the program, and the *exact* error message that you're getting. Don't paraphrase, copy from your command window.

Comment: Okay I revised it:

Using Eclipse IDE (Juno)
Click Run 
Message on Console: Error: Could not find or load main class JavaFixHistoryMiner
This was an imported file, I also added an external library